# Andengine A Moving Ball example, juddering / lag

Tags: andengine

In the Andengine "A Moving Ball" example, I experience a "jump" in the animation every 5 seconds or so ie. The lateral movement is not always smooth, it seems to skip a few pixels. I'm running this on a Samsung Galaxy SII. I also noticed this on the emulator.

[A Moving Ball example](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/introduction-moving-ball-example-and-some-other-things-t2514.html)

This is a problem for me as I'm creating an environment of ten bouncing balls and every few seconds I get this judder effect.

I'm looking for a very consistent movement, similar to say the baloons in "Crazy Pill":

[Crazy Pill](http://www.andengine.org/forums/project-development-blogs/crazy-pill-hd-released-t5479.html)

Has anyone noticed this occassional lag or any idea how to create a smooth movement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see if this discussion and solution helps

[Jittering texture when using BoundCamera](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post29525.html)